# How to display all events of the year?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to display all the events of the year starting by the current date, so essentially from March to December, I tried setting up the property `visibleRange` as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'list' ],

  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'listDay'
  },
  views: {
    listDay: { buttonText: 'list day' },
    listWeek: { buttonText: 'list week' }
  },

  defaultView: 'listWeek',
  navLinks: true, 
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true,
  events: <?= json_encode($events) ?>,
  visibleRange: {
     start: '2020-03-01',
     end: '2020-12-31'
  }
});

calendar.render();
});
```

the problem's that I get only the month of `March` is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get only the month of March

Actually, according to your code, what you will get is only a single week, or a single day. You cannot even show a whole month based on what you have written.

The issue with your attempt though is a simple logical one. You are defined views as `listWeek` and `listDay`. The names in these fix a period of time - "week" and "day" which the views will cover. This fixed period takes priority over any `visibleRange` setting.

If you want your view to take account of the `visibleRange`, then you must just specify the view name, without a fixed time period in its name:

```
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'list'
},
defaultView: 'list',
```

The above however will restrict you to only the exact time period specified. You cannot move to another year. To make this dynamic, you can use a function to calculate the visible range every time the view needs changing:

```
visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
  var yr = currentDate.getFullYear();
  return {
    start: yr + '-03-01',
    end: yr + '-12-31'
  }
},
dateIncrement: { "years": 1}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWbgyGZ

P.S. Specifying a view name without a time period is demonstrated in the [visibleRange documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange) already.

Comment: just a question: how can I go back to the previous year or next year? 'cause with the `visibleRange` I can't navigate the other years

Comment: Ah, if you want it dynamic you can use a function to get the Visible Range. See my updated answer, above (I also updated the demo).